# Setting a property of a custom view class for a chat app in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, properties

I am trying to display every message the user of my app receives or sends. To do so, I created a custom view class called MessageView. This class has a property called transcript containing the information about the sent or received message.

How should I use this class ? For now, I am creating a pointer to an instance of the class MessageView and setting the transcript property directly in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method of my view controller (where I would like to display the message view for each transcript). Here is the code where I am calling the class:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Transcript *transcript = [self.transcripts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Get the message view
    MessageView *messageView = (MessageView *)[cell viewWithTag:MESSAGE_VIEW_TAG];
    // Set up the message view for this transcript
    messageView.transcript = transcript;
    NSLog(@"%@", messageView.transcript.message);
    return cell;
}
```

Even though *transcript points to the correct information, I'm having trouble setting its value to the transcript property of messageView (messageView.transcript). Indeed, the log statement prints "null".

I've checked and I am correctly importing the MessageView class header in the view controller file. I've also declared a nonatomic and strong property transcript in the MessageView header interface.

Then, why doesn't my cell displays the MessageView ? If anyone has answers or links to similar questions, it would be greatly appreciated. I'm having trouble finding documentation about my problem. Thank you very much by advance!!

Comment: Have you verified whether `messageView` is `nil` or not?

Comment: A few things: Is cell nil? Is messageView nil? Settings transcript to messageView automatically set some text (visual?)?

Comment: @rmaddy indeed `messageView`is `nil` meaning than the problem comes from the following line of code: `MessageView *messageView = (MessageView *)[cell viewWithTag:MESSAGE_VIEW_TAG];`  Isn't my declaration valid ? I never used tag before, does this mean that the MessageView class isn't proper?

Comment: Make sure the message view's tag is set to the same value as your `MESSAGE_VIEW_TAG` value.